# What does this event mean, "Cancelling deletion of Pod", "TaintManagerEviction'

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

```
I1209 00:01:25.090381 10 event.go:294 "Event occurred" object="default/POD_NAME"
kind="Pod"
apiVersion=""
type="Normal"
reason="TaintManagerEviction"
message="Cancelling deletion of Pod default/POD_NAME"
```

I've googled and tried to look for source code.

Comment: What is the output of get events? `kubectl get events`

Comment: Thanks for the response. After looking again today, I found the api server found the kubelet as unresponsive and deleted the node after the grace period, and this message above was not related.